# Search opposite values in table Part 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have the following Initial Data, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/103607 with the relevant code which gets the data to collate all amounts which are the same (absolute values) with the same account code.

I am now looking to have the output such that it only includes pairs of items.

For example in the table below for account code 1 we have 3 values that are +-10. I would like the code to only include 2 of these ignoring the third such that value 1 + value 2 = 0, ensuring account code is the same.

I cannot think of how this may be possible unless i include a statement like

```
T1.[Amount] + T2[Amount] = 0
```

But this does not seem to work

**Current SQL code**

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        CTE  T1
WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT * FROM CTE AS T2
   WHERE t1.[Account Code] = T2.[Account Code]
   AND   t1.Amount = -t2.Amount
 ) 
 ORDER BY [Account Code], ABS(Amount)
```

[image: Initial Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you have is that you have repeating amounts.  So, all `10`s match all `-10`s -- even if there are not the same number.

The solution is to enumerate the rows for each amount, using `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Then, you can align the matches.

You can do this using window functions (without `EXISTS`):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Account Code], ABS(Amount), seqnum) as matches
      FROM (SELECT cte.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Account Code], Amount ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
            FROM cte
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE matches = 2
ORDER BY [Account Code], Amount;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/103616) is a db<>fiddle.

The innermost subquery enumerates the amounts for each account.

The middle subquery then enumerates the absolute value of the amounts for each sequence number.  Because the values can only be positive or negative -- and there are no duplicates because of `ROW_NUMBER()` -- a value of `2` indicates a match.

Comment: i don't quite understand why this works? would you mind elaborating on the logic? is it simply that once the script identifies a match (i.e. where match =2 rows) it then no longer considers that initial row. so in your example it stops looking for a secondary match for the +10

Comment: can i ask how this ensures the criteria that the account code must be the same? in my above snip the account codes are correctly in order, however, if they weren't how would we ensure this remains a key criteria

Comment: @Newbie . . . The question *does* explain how this works.  The `PARTITION BY` assures that the account is the same.